# How to change the dict to string with own style?

Tags: python, json

I aim at changing dict type to a string like : `name=tom&age=12%sex=m`

firstly, i do like this :

```
params=sorted([(k, v) for k, v in dic.items()])
src=""
for param in params:
    src+=param[0]+"="+param[1]+"&"
return src[:-1]
```

but i want to get some more way that can all finish the changeing.

i thought about the json package built-in python.
i do like this :

```
json.dumps(dict_arguments,sort_keys=True,separators=['&','='])
```

and the result comes out:

```
{"a"=1234&"b"=34532&"c"=3452}
```

it's a string type.it's obvious that it do not solve my problem.

so ,i want to know :

1,could you teach me some more way about change the look-like from dict to string?

2,if the json package can solve the problme? how can i change the `{"a"=1234&"b"=34532&"c"=3452}` to `{a=1234&b=34532&c=3452}`,then it would be sasy for me .

much obliged to all of you~

Comment: how does the original `dict` look like? Is it a `dict` or a `list` of `dict`s?

Comment: hello~the original dict like this:`{'a':1234,'c':3452,'b':34532}`,it has the `'`,also,the value ,such as 1234,may would be `'a':'12'`,i want get a way that like can change the dict to string ,just like the arguments in url .but ,i does not get a good idea.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What seems like you're doing is changing a `dict` into url `params`, you can do [urlencode](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlencode).

```
>>> import urllib
>>> a = {'a':123,'b':234,'c':345}
>>> urllib.urlencode(a)
'a=123&c=345&b=234'
```

Comment: In Python 3, it's [`urllib.parse.urlencode`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlencode).

Comment: yes! i am doing the changeing of a dict to url params.thanks!